# Rails - should i use a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a Student and a Teacher model in my app.  I want a teacher to be able to create a Task that the Student can complete multiple times, but I also want the Student to be able to create his/her own Task. This is my current model structure:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :teacher
 belongs_to :student
 has_many :completed_tasks

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :teacher
 has_many :tasks
 has_many :completed_tasks

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :students
 has_many :tasks

class CompletedTask < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :student
 belongs_to :task
```

In my views, I want a teacher to be able to add Tasks for his/her students.  When the Students view their Tasks, they see the Teacher's available tasks and can add their own. Students then mark the tasks as complete in a separate view. Should I consider using polymorphic association for this?  My situation seems a bit different from how it's used in [Ryan Bates' Railscast #154](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) since the Teacher and Student are interacting with the tasks in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a polymorphic association on `Task` to denote the creator of the task. The association between `Teacher` and `Task` may be unnecessary, unless a teacher can have available tasks that were *not* created by them. If that's the case, keep the current association to teacher, but if not, you only need an association for the creator.

Instead of `CompletedTask`, I would use a class called `Assignment`, that belongs to both a task and a student, and also has a `completed` flag, that defaults to false. This allows for tracking which students are assigned which tasks, whether the tasks are ongoing or completed.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :polymorphic => true

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :assigned_students, :through => :assignments, :source => :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :created_tasks, :as => :creator, :class_name => 'Task'

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :assigned_tasks, :through => :assignments, :source => :task
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :created_tasks, :as => :creator, :class_name => 'Task'
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :task

  scope :complete, where(:completed => true)
  scope :incomplete, where(:completed => false)
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.  I should have explained that I want it to be possible for the same task to be completed more than once on different days, which is why I have the CompletedTask model.  Is there a better way to allow for this?

Comment: Also, I want all Students that belong to the Teacher to see the task and be able to complete it, which is why I linked it to the Teacher and didn't have an assignee.  Again, do you think there is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you definitely want to update your question with that info re: CompletedTask. In that case, what you have for CompletedTask is probably ok, though I would consider renaming it, to `Completion` or something, for clarity.

Comment: To get a teacher's tasks when you have a student already, you can just do: `@student.teacher.created_tasks`

Comment: @NicSlim I'm going to update the answer in light of your newest comments.